# How to track if file was selected with javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, upload, input, field

So If I have an input field:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

I click it and select a file and when I press `Open` I would like to submit the form and upload the file without clicking the button added by `<input>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As goreSplatter points out below, be careful that this behavior isn't a surprise in terms of the user experience. For instance, it may be perfectly valid to do this with something that attaches files to an email like GMail does; but unless the user has an opportunity to cancel those attachments, etc., before things are finalized, you might be falling down a UX pothole. But I expect you've probably already worked out the UX aspect and are not doing something silly. :-)

Answering the question: You can do this by using a `change` event handler, e.g., `onchange=` or the DOM2 equivalent via `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on IE).

Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/exone3)):

```
hookEvent(document.getElementById('fileInput'),
          'change',
          inputChanged);

function inputChanged() {
  display("The input's value changed");
}
```

...where `hookEvent` is your utility function for hooking up an event handler (see the link below for one example, but it's not optimized; if you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), they'll include a means of hooking events cross-browser).

The example linked above works on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera for Linux, IE6 and IE7 on Windows, and so is fairly likely to be well-supported overall.

Comment: +1 for the scary suggestion. It works. That's going to be an annoying website, though...

Comment: Interesting stuff, thanks very much it works perfectly! I don't use any libraries, but I don't really understand how this works, I mean how the event listener works? Is it working like comet? The element itself starts the function when it's changed or does this works like `setInterval`, so it checks always if the element has changed?

Comment: @CIRK: The event is triggered by the browser when the element's value changes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#common-event-behaviors